# ExternalInterface as3 and ajax (jQuery) not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, externalinterface

this part of code works in all browsers but not in IE. Can you help me fix this?

```
function getData(userId, instrumentId, minStep) {
    alert(1); // worked!
    console.log(userId, instrumentId, minStep);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/controllers/ajax.php',
        data: "instrument=" + instrumentId + '&user=' + userId,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(2); // doesn't work
            document.getElementById("chart").dataFromJS(msg, minStep); // "chart" - id of flash player object loaded using swfobject
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work in IE, what's the error or problem?

Comment: I'd start by getting rid on console.log as that's not supported in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was something really stupid, at least after I realized what was. Try to don't use console.log in IE... maybe will be the same, good luck ;)